# Codeigniter passing no URI segment

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using codeigniter for a project.

The URL is segmented like this:

example.com/admin/events

example.com/admin/events/add

I have a class called Admin which has a function called events

```
function events($data)
{
  echo $data;
}
```

this will echo 'add' for the events/add page but when I try and access the events page alone i get an error

```
Missing argument 1 for Admin::events()
```

I thought that I could make two functions, one with a variable being passed and one without but apprently php doesn't allow that.

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare Admin::events()
```

How can I make this work?
Thanks.

Comment: thats solve your problem? let me know how can I improve my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try that

```
function events($data = NULL)
{
  echo $data;
}
```